# Bash function processing on arrays

Tags: bash

Why does bash complain with

```
bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
```

when calling the following function.

```
ary=( "PROGL" "TYPOG" )
seqn=( "THIS" "THAT" )
outa=$( my_func "${ary[@]}" "${seqn[@]}" )
```

Here is the function

```
my_func ()
 {
  ##
  declare -n incl="$1" excl="$2"

  local isufx=()

  if (( ${#incl[@]} > 0 )); then

    for ext in "${incl[@]}"; do

      if [[ "$ext" == "PROGL" ]]; then
        isufx+=( --include=\*.{rc,el,c,f} )
        continue
      elif [[ "$ext" == "PEXTD" ]]; then
        isufx+=( --include=\*.{rc,el,c,f} )
        isufx+=( --include=\*.{cp,cpp,f90,f95,f03,f08} )
        continue
      elif [[ "$ext" == "TYPOG" ]]; then
        isufx+=( --include=\*.{org,texi,tex} )
        continue
      fi  

  printf '%s\0' "${isufx[@]}"
 }
```

Using Ubuntu 18.04.

Would it be better to use `typeset` rather than `declare`?

Comment: Which operating system and version are you using?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a typical [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) question ... So, all I can do to help is to highlight some points you mentioned and hopefully this will at least help you avoid dead ends and point you away from the wrong direction.

Hopefully, this will help you as well to see how many separate, focused, clear and individual questions are included in your single general question above so that in the future you might break them down and ask for each one separately if you wish.

**First,**

The option `-n` is used to declare a reference variable [`nameref`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameters.html) and cannot be used to declare an array ... Please see [the `bash` builtin `declare`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-declare) ... Please, see the demonstration below:

```bash
$ array=( "word1" "word2 space" "word3 *" )

# This will throw an error:

$ function my_func {
  local -n my_array=( "$@" )
  my_array+=("This" "That")
  printf '%s\n' "${my_array[@]}"
}

$ my_func "${array[@]}"
bash: local: my_array: reference variable cannot be an array
word1
word2 space
word3 *
This
That


# This will not work:

$ function my_func {
  local -n my_array="$1"
  my_array+=("This" "That")
  printf '%s\n' "${my_array[@]}"
}

$ my_func "${array[@]}"
This
That
```

You can, however, use a `nameref` and pass the array/s names(*not elements*) as positional arguments, but this has its own disadvantage as well ... Because, you're not actually recreating the passed array/s as local array/s inside your function, but rather merely referencing the original array/s by another name and therefore changes are not "*local to your function*" as you might think ... Please, see the demonstration below:

```bash
$ array=( "word1" "word2 space" "word3 *" )
$ array2=( "word4" "word5" "word6" )

$ function my_func {
  local -n my_array="$1"
  local -n my_array2="$2"
  my_array+=("This" "That")
  my_array2+=("This2" "That2")
  printf '%s\n' "${my_array[@]}"
  printf '%s\n' "${my_array2[@]}"
}

# Run the function:

$ my_func "array" "array2"
word1
word2 space
word3 *
This
That
word4
word5
word6
This2
That2

# Run the same function again:

$ my_func "array" "array2"
word1
word2 space
word3 *
This
That
This
That
word4
word5
word6
This2
That2
This2
That2

# Print original arrays

$ echo "${array[@]}"
word1 word2 space word3 * This That This That

$ echo "${array2[@]}"
word4 word5 word6 This2 That2 This2 That2
```

**Second,**

Passing array elements as arguments to a function with `my_func "${array[@]}"` will not pass them as an array but rather as positional arguments i.e. first element as `$1`, second element as `$2` ... and so on ... Therefore you should rebuild the array inside the function with `array=( "$@" )` ... See the demonstration below:

```bash
$ array=( "word1" "word2 space" "word3 *" )

# This will work:

$ function my_func {
  local my_array=( "$@" )
  my_array+=("This" "That")
  printf '%s\n' "${my_array[@]}"
}

$ my_func "${array[@]}"
word1
word2 space
word3 *
This
That

# This will not work:

$ function my_func {
  local my_array=( "$1" )
  my_array+=("This" "That")
  printf '%s\n' "${my_array[@]}"
}

$ my_func "${array[@]}"
word1
This
That
```

Needless to say that if you pass more than one array to the function, they will be hard to split back into original separate arrays and they will be combined ... Please, see the demonstration below:

```bash
$ array=( "word1" "word2 space" "word3 *" )
$ array2=( "word4" "word5" "word6" )

$ function my_func {
  local my_array=( "$@" )
  my_array+=("This" "That")
  printf '%s\n' "${my_array[@]}"
}

$ my_func "${array[@]}" "${array2[@]}"
word1
word2 space
word3 *
word4
word5
word6
This
That
```

**Third,**

You don't really need to handle an array in your script like this in order to make it available inside a function ... If an array(*or variable*) is defined in your script, then you can just call it directly inside your function like so:

```bash
$ array=( "word1" "word2 space" "word3 *" )

$ function my_func {
  local my_array=( "${array[@]}" )
  my_array+=("This" "That")
  printf '%s\n' "${my_array[@]}"
}

$ my_func
word1
word2 space
word3 *
This
That
```

**Fourth,**

With proper quoting(*as it should be in most cases*), array expansion will pass each element as a single [token](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Definitions.html#index-token) ... Therefore you cant assign command options and their argument/s to an array element and expect it to work as usual in a command ... Please, see the demonstration below:

```bash
# This works:

$ echo -e 'new\nline'
new
line

# This doesn't:

$ array=( "-e 'new\nline'" )

$ echo "${array[@]}"
-e 'new\nline'
```

**Fifth,**

As for the warning message you see:

> bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input.

That is actually the least of your problems ... It, however, simply means that you/your commands asked to include null byte/s(*i.e. `\0` from `printf '%s\0' "${isufx[@]}"` in your function that you used in the command substitution*) in/during a string creation/definition process(*e.g. in the command substitution syntax*) that will need its end to be identified in order to be handled properly later on ... and `bash` can't do that as it actually uses [C-style strings](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm)(*which are terminated by a null character '\0'*) and therefor `bash` ignores that and informs you about it ... So, simply change that and the message shouldn't appear anymore.

Comment: I have read that passing arrays to a function is usually done with a `nameref`.  But I am totally unaware of how such approach is to be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You expicitly print a `\0` byte inside a command substitution. To overly simplify, this is what you effectively do:

```
outa=$( printf '\0' )
```

which command on its own also prints the same warning.

Shell variables are represented internally as `\0`-terminated strings, therefore cannot contain the `\0` byte as part of their actual value. Thus, when a command inside the command substitution emits this byte, `bash` has to strip it off from the value assigned to the variable. Hence the warning.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using path-like variables (colon-separated lists) instead of arrays, if your data doesn't contain colons. I use Stephen Collyer's bash_path_funcs, described in Linux Journal way back in 2000:

https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3645
https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3768
https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3935

The `addpath` function adds an entry to a path only if it is not there in the first place. `delpath -n` deletes all non-existent directories from a path.

You can get the `pathfunc.tgz` file from  https://web.archive.org/web/20061210054813/http://www.netspinner.co.uk:80/Downloads/pathfunc.tgz